# How to drag and Drop in Selenium when Source and Destination elements are not on same page

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with two sections one with frame and another with out frame. User wants to Drag and Drop from one section to another.

Selenium provides dragAndDrop(WebElement source, WebElement target) using Actions Class. When i use this method, the control should move the element from section without frame to section with frame Now to do so, control needs to Switch to Frame and then Drop it.

Internally dragAndDrop method first Click And Hold then Move the Mouse and finally do the button release. There is no scenario to switch to frame first and then drop it in Frame.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/810

Comment: Read out this https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/drag-and-drop-action-in-selenium/, it explain how Drag and Drop work.